# Github img url in stylsheet not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

Trying to do a background image stored in my repo/Images in github. Using the code:

```html
html { 
  background: url((-myrepodirectoryurl-)/blob/master/Images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

No image appears.

Also, I tried:

```html
html { 
  background: url(/Images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

and:

```html
html { 
  background: url(../Images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

But no image appears? Nothing at all. Just a white space!

Cheers

Comment: Do you see any exceptions in your console? Also, have you tried using a different host? Sites like github prevent you from accessing image/remote content directly, and will usually add headers to prevent browser from rendering them as content.

Comment: use a div 100% width height instead of html.

Comment: @SlimShady This would be an issue if it was a empty div. The HTML tag covers the whole page and can't be resized.

Comment: You probably have the wrong url. Your url should be: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/YOUR_NAME/YOUR_REP/master/path/to/image.jpg` and not `https://github.com/YOUR_NAME/YOUR_REP/master/path/to/image.jpg`

Comment: What confuses me, is on a page on the website (The gcse chemistry page) I have used about 4 images from within folders stored on github. They work fine (linked in the same way) The only difference here, is that its in my stylesheet. Does that make a difference?